Putting white spaces between words in odfpy python module
As in the topic above, is it possible to add whitespaces berween words in the odfpy module?
I've tried using "/t" or multiple spaces like " ", or few Span with " " and it always displays compressed as one white space.
from odf.opendocument import OpenDocumentText
from odf.style import Style, TextProperties
from odf.text import P, Span


document = OpenDocumentText()
doc_s = document.styles

boldstyle = Style(name="Bold", family="text")
boldstyle.addElement(TextProperties(attributes={"fontweight":"bold"}))
doc_s.addElement(boldstyle)

line = P(text = "")
boldpart = Span(stylename = boldstyle, text="0009")

whitespace = Span(text="    ")
whitespace_01 = Span(text="\t")

line.addElement(boldpart) 
line.addElement(whitespace)
line.addElement(whitespace_01)

line.addText(" some text")
document.text.addElement(line)

document.save("file.odt")

I just want to put few white spaces or TAB between the number and text, maybe some word spacing.
Output:
0009 some text

What i need is:
0009    some text

Maybe I need to configure something before I use it?

See this link I found. I tested the tabstop and teletype and it works fine.

Its working! Thanks man!
